# PyGObject failed to install because of pycairo failing

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pycairo

I'm trying to install system wide `PyGObject`. But I'm struggling with some weird error that pops up when installer try to build `pycairo` wheel. I tried to upgrade and reinstall `setuptools` using `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools` but this did not help. Also tried to set `export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib` but also did not work. Error is:

```
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 290, in set_undefined_options
                setattr(self, dst_option, getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
                raise AttributeError(attr)
            AttributeError: install_layout. Did you mean: 'install_platlib'?
```

Seems like pycairo installer try to call some method/attribute that does not exist somehow.

How to fix this?

I'm using Python 3.11

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.7
```

Full install log below

````
$ sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall PyGObject 
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.46.0.tar.gz (723 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [121 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-69.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
      Collecting pycairo
        Using cached pycairo-1.25.1.tar.gz (347 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
        Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [93 lines of output]
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running build_py
            creating build
            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11
            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo
            copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo
            copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo
            copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo
            running build_ext
            building 'cairo._cairo' extension
            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11
            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/bufferproxy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/bufferproxy.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/cairomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/cairomodule.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/context.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/context.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/device.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/device.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/enums.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/enums.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/error.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/error.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/font.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/font.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/glyph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/glyph.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/matrix.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/matrix.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/misc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/misc.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/path.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/path.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/pattern.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/pattern.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/rectangle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/rectangle.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/region.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/region.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/surface.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/surface.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/textcluster.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/textcluster.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=25 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c cairo/textextents.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/textextents.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Winline -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wswitch-default -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -std=c99
            x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/bufferproxy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/cairomodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/context.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/device.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/enums.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/error.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/font.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/glyph.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/matrix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/misc.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/path.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/pattern.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/rectangle.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/region.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/surface.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/textcluster.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/textextents.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcairo -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11/cairo/_cairo.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
            installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
            running install
            running install_lib
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/tmp/tmpieb1oamc_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
                main()
              File "/tmp/tmpieb1oamc_in_process.py", line 345, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/tmp/tmpieb1oamc_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
                return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
                return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
                self.run_setup()
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
                exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
              File "setup.py", line 549, in <module>
                main()
              File "setup.py", line 513, in main
                setup(
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
                return run_commands(dist)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
                dist.run_commands()
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
                self.run_command(cmd)
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 335, in run
                self.run_command('install')
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
                return orig.install.run(self)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 622, in run
                self.run_command(cmd_name)
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
                cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
                self.finalize_options()
              File "setup.py", line 416, in finalize_options
                du_install_lib.finalize_options(self)
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 17, in finalize_options
                self.set_undefined_options('install',('install_layout','install_layout'))
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 290, in set_undefined_options
                setattr(self, dst_option, getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
                raise AttributeError(attr)
            AttributeError: install_layout. Did you mean: 'install_platlib'?
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
      Failed to build pycairo
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.```
````